# Flask UnboundLocalError: local variable 'latitu' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, flask

I have two files csv the first is for restaurants and the second is for tourist places so I have two list of longitude and latitude and I want to view them in a map, my problem is when I want to view both at the same time i get this error :

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'latitu' referenced before assignment

I managed this code as below :

```
fullmap = Map(
        identifier="fullmap",
        varname="fullmap",
        style=(
            "height:100%;"
            "width:100%;"
            "top:0;"
            "left:0;"
            "position:absolute;"
            "z-index:200;"
        ),
        lat= 46.160329 ,
        lng=-1.151139,
        markers=[
            {
            'icon': icons.dots.red,
            'title': prix,
            'lat': lat,
            'lng': lng,
            'infobox': (
                titre+ " <b style='color:#ffcc00;'> " +prix+ "</b>"
                "<h3>surface:<b style='color:#33BBFF;'>" +surface+"</b></h2>"
                "<br>Longitude: "+lng+ ""
                "<br>Latitude: "+lat+ ""
            )
        }for lat,lng ,titre,surface,prix in zip(Lat,Lng,Titre,Surface,Prix),
        {
            'icon': icons.dots.yellow,
            'lat': latitu,
            'lng': longitu,
            'infobox': (
                title+ " <b style='color:#ffcc00;'> </b>"
                "<br>Longitude: "+latitu+ ""
                "<br>Latitude: "+lat+ ""
            )
        }for latitu,longitu ,title in zip(Latitude,Longitude,Title)
        ],
        circles=[{
        'fill_color': '#FF00FF',
        'fill_opacity': 0.2,
        'center': {
            'lat': 46.160329,
            'lng': -1.151139
        },
        'radius': 1300,
        'infobox': "Centre ville"
    }],
        fit_markers_to_bounds = True
        # maptype = "TERRAIN",
        # zoom="5"

    )
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have many varible name mismatches in your code, some are even contextual like `"<br>Longitude: "+latitu+ ""`.

Comment: I changed the names of the variables but still it does not work

Comment: Python gave you more details about the error, including the line that failed. Please put the entire traceback into your question. And consider making a copy of this script and reducing it to a smaller example demonstrating the problem That is frequently enough to find the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have what looks to be variables named wrong, but more fundamentally you are trying to build two list is a single comprehension.  You need to build two comprehensions like:

```
markers=[
    {
        'icon': icons.dots.red,
        'title': prix,
        'lat': lat,
        'lng': lng,
        'infobox': (
            titre+ " <b style='color:#ffcc00;'> " +prix+ "</b>"
            "<h3>surface:<b style='color:#33BBFF;'>" +surface+"</b></h2>"
            "<br>Longitude: "+lng+ ""
            "<br>Latitude: "+lat+ ""
        )
    } for lat,lng ,titre,surface,prix in zip(Lat,Lng,Titre,Surface,Prix)
] + [
    {
        'icon': icons.dots.yellow,
        'lat': latitu,
        'lng': longitu,
        'infobox': (
            title+ " <b style='color:#ffcc00;'> </b>"
            "<br>Longitude: "+latitu+ ""
            "<br>Latitude: "+lat+ ""
        )
    } for latitu,longitu ,title in zip(Latitude,Longitude,Title)
],
```

The fundamental change is the `] + [` about half way down.

Comment: thank you for your answer but in can showing only the red icons (tourist places) not the yellow icons